Expose go_router routers based on user auth status and maintain the state of their navigation activity to navigate them where they left after logout
The problem is that once the go router state refreshes all state is lost.
Is there a way to cause redirects without causing the loss of state
I have an app that requires the user to be authenticated in order to use any of its features.
So we have the auth page which can be accessed only if the user is not logged in.
Once the user logs in, they may use the features. But the moment the user pushes the app to background the user is logged out automatically.
This user state is maintained as a bool in a Riverpod state provider.
Go router is also being used here
Now once the user comes back from the background they must be presented with the login screen(since they are logged out)
Once they login successfully, they should be able to access the screen where they left off before pushing to app to background
For example lets say I go like this after login:
home > detail > profile
and then I push the app to background ( so logged out ) and then open the app again
Now login screen should open and after I login I should see the profile page and which I go back I should see the detail page.
That state should be preserved
I tried ref.watch(authStateProvider)  and provided and the router from a riverpod provider by listening to the authState
But once the user state changes I'm not able to get anything that the user accessed previously.

Typically you should store the user auth state in a persistent storage that is read in the provider body.

But that's not even the question. To be clean I have auth state in a riverpod provider and I don't want it to be persisted using SharedPreferences. The question is after is user is logged out when the app is sent to background and again logs in how do I show the user the app how it was and the point they left the screen like the entire navigation history?

But if you need this type of history precision, this information should me persisted somewhere outside its Runtime State. Am I wrong?
If I were you, I'd implement a method to store somewhere (can be locally on users device, api database, whatever) the last pages that were seen by user. And to store this, I would call this method on logout flow.

That's exactly what I want, but say I have a bottom sheet in a page or a form which I want to persist. How do you do persist that state also. Please explain the entire approach and things you would use as the answer. Plus even if I were to store the state and after logout and  then login, what you want me to do is to push those routes again. Isn't that like a hacky way?
